# Why do I get an all-black/grayscale image when I load this PNG in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, file

When I run this code:

```
>> I = imread('D:\Works\matlab\SecCode.php.png','png');
>> imshow(I);
```

It always shows an all-black image. What's wrong with it?

The image I'm using is this one:

[image]

Comment: The MATLAB code looks fine. Are you sure the file doesn't contain all black? Have you opened it in another image viewer to check?

Comment: Would you be able to add the image to the post? I get the feeling there's something about the format of the image that is causing problems, and in order to help you we'll probably need to see it.

Comment: Yes,I've attached it in the post.

Comment: I think it's the alpha problem.try solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172389/how-do-i-make-a-png-with-transparency-appear-transparent-in-matlab

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ahhh, I see now. The problem is you have an [indexed image](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html#f2-155) and need to get the colormap argument from [`imread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) as well. Try this:

```
[I, map] = imread('D:\Works\matlab\SecCode.php.png', 'png');
imshow(I, map);
```

A description of the different types of images in MATLAB can be found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html). Here's a brief summary:

- **Binary images**: The image is a [`logical`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logical.html) array where each pixel has the value 0 or 1.
- [**Indexed images**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html#f2-155): The pixels in the image store indices into a colormap, which is an M-by-3 array of RGB values. The colormap is often stored with the indexed image in the image file.
- [**Intensity (Grayscale) images**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html#f2-175): The pixels in the image each contain a single value representing the intensity.
- [**RGB (Truecolor) images**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html#f2-12468): The image is an M-by-N-by-3 array where each pixel has a red, green, and blue color component.

Comment: Is this what you mean by **indexed** :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_color  ?

Comment: @user198729: Yes, that is what I meant. I also added some MATLAB documentation links above for you.

Comment: Thanks,can you also elaborate a little about this image,which is found in your link:http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/introa.gif

Comment: @user198729: That image illustrates a Truecolor image. They are 3-D data arrays (M-by-N-by-3). In that picture, a section of the image is displayed as a set of 3 M-by-N arrays, one for red values, one for green values, and one for blue values. The values range from 0 to 1 for each pixel, with higher values indicating a larger component of that color for that pixel.

Comment: Yes,but which 3 of them denotes the RGB for the **same** point in the image?

Comment: @user198729: Note that there is one value shown in **bold** in the each of the red, green, and blue panels. These values create a reddish brown color (probably one of the pixels for one of the dark red peppers). Even though there's a circle around the yellow pepper in the image, the data in the inset is probably for a different area and is just there to illustrate what the matrix contents typically look like.