# How do I use graythresh on an indexed image in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

```
I = imread('coins.png');
level = graythresh(I);
BW = im2bw(I,level);
imshow(BW)
```

The above is an example from the MATLAB documentation using a grayscale image. How can I make it work with an indexed image like [image]
 in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586539/why-do-i-get-an-all-black-grayscale-image-when-i-load-this-png-in-matlab)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first convert the indexed image and its colormap into a grayscale image using the function [IND2GRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/ind2gray.html):

```
[X,map] = imread('SecCode.php.png');  %# Read the indexed image and colormap
grayImage = ind2gray(X,map);          %# Convert to grayscale image
```

Then you can apply the code you have above:

```
level = graythresh(grayImage);     %# Compute threshold
bwImage = im2bw(grayImage,level);  %# Create binary image
imshow(bwImage);                   %# Display image
```

**EDIT:**

If you wanted to make this a generalized approach for any type of image, here's one way you could do it:

```
%# Read an image file:

[X,map] = imread('an_image_file.some_extension');

%# Check what type of image it is and convert to grayscale:

if ~isempty(map)                %# It's an indexed image if map isn't empty
  grayImage = ind2gray(X,map);  %# Convert the indexed image to grayscale
elseif ndims(X) == 3            %# It's an RGB image if X is 3-D
  grayImage = rgb2gray(X);      %# Convert the RGB image to grayscale
else                            %# It's already a grayscale or binary image
  grayImage = X;
end

%# Convert to a binary image (if necessary):

if islogical(grayImage)         %# grayImage is already a binary image
  bwImage = grayImage;
else
  level = graythresh(grayImage);     %# Compute threshold
  bwImage = im2bw(grayImage,level);  %# Create binary image
end

%# Display image:

imshow(bwImage);
```

This should cover *most* image types, with the exception of some outliers (like [alternate color spaces for TIFF images](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/imread.html#f25-721031)).

Comment: But RGB image is M*N*3,which is not grayscale image:M*N,right?

Comment: @user198729: The function GRAYTHRESH still works for RGB images, but maybe not *exactly* the same way as it does for grayscale images, so I updated my answer to use IND2GRAY instead.

Comment: Last question,how to make it a generalized function that can grayscale various kinda images?

Comment: That is an impressively complete solution.