# imread changes the image after reading it in

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have a folder full of `.png` files and I want to convert them to `.jpg`. I wrote this code to process all of them and to convert them to `jpg`

```
imgPath = 'C:\Users\SET1\writer_2\';
imgType = '*.png'; % change based on image type
images  = dir([imgPath imgType]);

newPath = 'C:\Users\Desktop\SET1\';

for idx = 1:length(images)
    Seq{idx} = imread([imgPath images(idx).name]);

    imwrite(Seq{idx}, strcat(newPath,images(idx).name, '.jpg'));
end
```

But I noticed that when it reads the image in it somehow changes it. For example here is the original image

[image]

Here is the image read in, and this is what is saved as the output of imwrite

[image]

You can basically see the change. First of it inverted the image, then it converted the strokes of the pen to a collection of dots, as in what happens when one performs `im2bw`

I do not understand as to why this is happening and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the image is color mapped. You need to read in the files like so:

```
[I,map]=imread(yourPngFile);
imshow(I,map);
imwrite(I,map,outfilename);
```

If you want you can convert it and save it in your cell array as an RGB image:

```
Seq{idx} = ind2rgb(I,map);
```

Source:

[How do I load and show a PNG image in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586539/how-do-i-load-and-show-a-png-image-in-matlab)