# How do I make a png with transparency appear transparent in MatLab?

Tags: image, matlab, png, transparent, alpha

I have an image with a transparent background, but when I open it in MATLAB, I get a black background.  I'm overlaying it on top of a background image. How can I get this to display? I've tried using the alpha function `alpha(image,0)` but it sets my entire image to 0.  Is it possible for me to set the alpha of individual pixels to be equal to 0?  That way I can run each pixel through a loop.

I'm not sure if this helps, but when I run a `imfinfo('ryu1.png')`, I get :

```
...
Transparency = 'alpha' 
SimpleTransparencyData = []
...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can read in your image using [`imread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html).  However, you need to specify additional output parameters if you want to grab the alpha channel.  You need to call it like this:

```
[im, map, alpha] = imread('ryu1.png');
```

`im` is your image read in, `map` is the colour map which we will ignore, but `alpha` contains the transparency information that you want.  First call `imshow` and record the handle to the image, then set your transparency with the `alpha` channel using the `set` command.  In other words:

```
[im, map, alpha] = imread('ryu1.png');
f = imshow(im);
set(f, 'AlphaData', alpha);
```

This should make the figure with the transparency intact.

---

## Addition (Thanks to Yvon)

Supposing you already have a background image loaded into MATLAB.  If you want to blend these two together, you need to do some alpha matting.  You use the alpha channel and mix the two together.  In other words, supposing your background image is stored in `img_background` and `img_overlay` is the image you want to go on top of the background, do this:

```
alphaMask = im2double(alpha); %// To make between 0 and 1
img_composite = im2uint8(double(img_background).*(1-alphaMask) + double(img_overlay).*alphaMask);
```

The first step is necessary as the alpha map that is loaded in will be the same type as the input image, which is usually `uint8`.  We need to convert this to a `double` image such that it goes in between `0` and `1`, and `im2double` is perfect to do this.  The second line converts each of the images to double precision so that we can compute this sum and in order to make the data types between the alpha mask and both images are compatible.  We then convert back to `uint8`.  You can then show this final image using `imshow`.

Comment: OP may want to overlay this image onto another one - `img_composite = img_background.*(1-alpha) + img_overlay.*alpha`

Comment: @Yvon - Good point!  I added in an extra blurb about how to alpha merge the two images together.  BTW, you'll need to convert the alpha mask so that it lies between `[0,1]` so that merging can be successful.  Thanks :)

Comment: Unfortunately I get the following message: Warning: Error creating or updating Image  Error in value of property  AlphaData
 Array is wrong shape or size . In addition, the binary image does not display.

Comment: @Sade That error can mean anything. Open up a new question and go into detail about your question.